# How do I get an array of all entitytypes of a specific entity?

Tags: 8

Hey there what I'm trying to do is to get all entity type ids from my custom config entity.
To load them all.

Example give:

I have an entity 'foo' and I create a new 'foo' named 'bar1' and another 'bar2' and so on how do I get those ids programmatically?

Better question

How do I get all entity_type_ids(or bundles dunno don't found a good entity hirarchie doku yet :( ) of an entity for example all types of the node entity?

Comment: Are you attempting to perform a query that gets entities of a certain content type and get their ids?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean "How do I get an array of all entities of a specific entity type?"

```
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery($entity_type_id)->execute();
```

Because an entity can only be of one type, to get the id of the entity type:

```
$entity_type_id = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
```

**Answer to the edited question:**

"How do I get an array of all bundle id's of a specific entity type?"

```
$bundles = \Drupal::entityManager()->getBundleInfo($entity_type_id);
```

Or all content types, which are bundles of the entity type `node`:

```
$content_types = \Drupal::entityManager()->getBundleInfo('node');
```

This function will be moved to it's own class before Drupal 9:

```
\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeBundleInfoInterface::getBundleInfo()
```

This is provided as a service:

```
$content_types = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getBundleInfo('node');
```

Answer (score 1):

If your entity type was an 'article' for example, you could perform

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type','article');
$nidlist = $query->execute();
```

$nidlist would then be an  array that contains all the IDs in the results in the query.

Comment: article is not an entity type, node is. article is a bundle (which is the generic term for what node calls node types)